# How to render a form in each row of data table?

Tags: javascript, datatables

I have the following page that's fetching data from a backend and show that data on a Datatable

In my table I have a column called Oid which is an input field with a default initial value retrieved from the backend, and another column which is a button. How can I create a function that whenever a button on any row is clicked can access the **Oid** value for the corresponding row for that button? Note that since the Oid row is an input field, if I edit the input field I need to be able to access the edited value and not the default value retrieved from the backend.

```js
let page = 1;
var exchange = "all";
var search = "";
var urlPage = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/mw_api/?page=" + page + "&exchange=" + exchange + "&search=" + search;

function loadTable() {
  urlPage = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/mw_api/?page=" + page + "&exchange=" + exchange + "&search=" + search;
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#mwdata').DataTable({
      "processing": true,
      "serverSide": true,
      "pageLength": 15,
      "ajax": {
        "data": function(d) {
          var info = $('#mwdata').DataTable().page.info();
          page = info.page + 1;
          search = d.search.value;
          urlPage = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/mw_api/?page=" + page + "&exchange=" + exchange + "&search=" + search;
          console.log(urlPage, page, 'SEARCH', search);
          $('#mwdata').DataTable().ajax.url(urlPage);
          page = info.page + 1;
          console.log(page);
        }
      },
      "columns": [{
          "data": "MarketName"
        },
        {
          "data": "CoinName"
        },
        {
          "data": "MainMarket"
        },
        {
          "data": "MarketType"
        },
        {
          "data": "Exchange"
        },
        {
          "data": "Bid"
        },
        {
          "data": "Oid",
          "render": function(data, type, row) {
            return "<input type='text' class='form-control' value='" + data + "'>";
          }
        },
        {
          "data": null,
          "defaultContent": "<button class='btn btn-primary'>Update</button>"
        }

      ]
    });


  });
}

function setExchange() {
  exchange = document.getElementById("exchanges").value;
  // reload the table
  $('#mwdata').DataTable().ajax.reload();
}

loadTable();
```

```html
<head>
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-/JqT3SQfawRcv/BIHPThkBvs0OEvtFFmqPF/lYI/Cxo="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-YvpcrYf0tY3lHB60NNkmXc5s9fDVZLESaAA55NDzOxhy9GkcIdslK1eN7N6jIeHz" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-QWTKZyjpPEjISv5WaRU9OFeRpok6YctnYmDr5pNlyT2bRjXh0JMhjY6hW+ALEwIH" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.5/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/2.0.2/css/dataTables.dataTables.css">
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.5/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
</head>
<div class="container">

  <table id="mwdata" class="display" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Market Name</th>
        <th>Coin Name</th>
        <th>Main Market</th>
        <th>Market Type</th>
        <th>Exchange</th>
        <th>Bid Price</th>
        <th>OID</th>
        <th>Update</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: I made a snippet. Please replace the ajax (which I assume works) with an example object so we can have a [mcve]. Also post RENDERED HTML intead of templating, lastly include relevant frameworks from CDN

Comment: Just to note: One other way to replace the Ajax is described in [I've been told to create a "runnable" example with "Stack Snippets". How do I do that?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/12567365) See "_If your code needs AJAX..._"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.cell(row, column)` function of the datatable plugin. But since this *is* a table, I like to use the DOM for this. That's right.

```js
document.querySelector('table').querySelectorAll(".btn").forEach(function(btn) {
  btn.addEventListener('click', function(ev) {
    var row = this.closest('tr');
    var tds = row.querySelectorAll(":scope>td")
    var td = tds[0] // 0 is first column
    var input = td.querySelector("input")
    var value = input.value
    alert(value)

  })
})
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<table border="1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" value="Joe Biden"></td>
      <td><button class="btn">Get Value</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" value="Jane Doe"></td>
      <td><button class="btn">Get Value</button></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Will this approach (`document.querySelector('table').querySelectorAll(".btn")`) take into account DataTables pagination? Would you need a delegated event handler for buttons not yet rendered (until the user navigates to the "next" DataTables page of results) via Ajax?

Comment: no, you would need to use the `page` [event](https://datatables.net/reference/event/page). alternatively, you can use inline javascript `<button onclick="yourFunction(this)">button</button>`